# PHP Echo a number using else if and greater than or less than

Tags: php, numbers, if-statement

I have a script which is like a whois database. This function returns site views and I want to echo between value.

How can I echo and return one result? If the number is say 4000, it should return only **1k-10k**

Rows are like

> 1550330
>
> 1000000

The code:

```
$siteTotalViews=1000000;
if($siteTotalViews <= 100){
    echo '0-100';
}
if($siteTotalViews <= 1000){
    echo '100-1k';
}
if($siteTotalViews <= 10000){
    echo '1k-10k';
}
if($siteTotalViews <= 100000){
    echo '10k-100k';
}
if($siteTotalViews <= 1000000){
    echo '100k-1 mil';
}
if($siteTotalViews <= 2000000){
    echo '1 mil-2 mil';
}
if($siteTotalViews <= 5000000){
    echo '2 mil-5 mil';
}
if($siteTotalViews <= 10000000){
    echo '5 mil-10 mil';
}
if($siteTotalViews >= 10000000){
    echo '10 mil +';
}
```

Comment: So, your question is...?

Comment: Sorry, why can't you use `elseif`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix:

```
$siteTotalViews=1000000;
if($siteTotalViews <= 100){
    echo '0-100';
}
//next else is new
else if($siteTotalViews <= 1000){
    echo '100-1k';
}
//next else is new
else if($siteTotalViews <= 10000){
    echo '1k-10k';
}
//next else is new
else if($siteTotalViews <= 100000){
    echo '10k-100k';
}
```

Better fix:

```
$names=array(
  100 => '0-100',
  1000 => '100-1k',
  10000 => '1k-10k',
  ...
}

foreach ($names as $count=>$name)
  if ($siteTotalViews<$count) break;

echo $name;
```

Comment: @Kaii So what's the problem? It will end up with $name having the last name in the array, which is exactly what we want. Unable to see a "wrong way round" here!

Answer (score 2):

You could create a function that return the interval. When the function hit the return statement it stops executing, so you will only get one value back. Then you can call the function and echo the result:

```
function getInterval($siteTotalViews) {

  if($siteTotalViews <= 100){
      return '0-100';
  }
  if($siteTotalViews <= 1000){
      return '100-1k';
  }

  ...

}

echo getInterval(1000);
```

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid No you shouldn't need to use else if, since if the first if-statement isn't valid it will just try the next until it reaches the one that is true.

Answer (score 2):

You could put all the limits and their corresponding text into an array and then loop over the reverse array to find the appropriate output. (`break`ing the loop when a limit has been hit)

```
$siteTotalViews=1000000;
$outputs = array(
  0 => '0-100',
  100 => '100-1k',
  1000 => '1k-10k',
  10000 => '10k-100k',
  100000 => '100k-1 mil',
  1000000 => '1 mil-2 mil',
  2000000 => '2 mil-5 mil',
  5000000 => '5 mil-10 mil',
  10000000 => '10 mil +' );
$outputs = array_reverse($outputs);

foreach ($outputs as $limit => $text) {
  if ($siteTotalViews >= $limit) {
    echo $text;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: What about speed of this compared to using an if and else if statement

Comment: almost the same. you should really not care about micro-optimization here. in fact, the count of ifs executed here is the same as it would be without the loop. the only overhead you have is the array and the loop - don't care about.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: Doesn't matter. It's a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$siteTotalViews=1000000;
 if($siteTotalViews >= 0 && $siteTotalViews <=100 ){    
echo '0-100'; } 
if($siteTotalViews >=101 && $siteTotalViews <= 1000){    
 echo '100-1k'; } 
.....
   if($siteTotalViews >= 10000000){     
echo '10 mil +'; }
```